# Rails perform inner join with active record complex query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, inner-join, has-many

I have to perform a complex active record query.

I have 5 models

Card Model

```
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :leads
  has_many :programs, through: :leads
end
```

Leads Model

```
class Lead < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :card
  belongs_to :program
end
```

Program Model

```
class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :leads
  has_many :cards, through: :leads
  belongs_to :school
end
```

School Model

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :programs
  belongs_to :representative
end
```

Representative Model

```
class Representative < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :schools
end
```

I want to count the number of cards each school and each representative has. A representative has many schools, a school has many programs, and  a program has many cards.

I know I have to perform an inner join but after some research I haven't found any precise instructions. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to create a relation between `School` and `Card` first and the same for `Represent`. Also I belive the word you are looking for is `Representative` - `Represent` is a verb - not a noun.

Comment: you are right I should use the word representative but it doesn't change the problem

Comment: Well somewhere along the line you need to link a card to a school id. How exactly to do that depends on the domain modeling. Maybe `Program` `belongs_to :school`

Comment: I could add a school_id and representative_id to the Card model but I know I can count each representative's cards with just an active record query

Comment: Right but how are you going to determine that a card is related to a school? That relation has to be stored somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a few more associations to some of your models should help a bit.

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  # in addition to existing relations
  has_many :leads, through: :programs
  has_many :cards, through: :leads
end

class Representative < ActiveRecord::Base
  # in addition to existing relations
  has_many :programs, through: :schools
  has_many :leads, through: :programs
  has_many :cards, through: :leads
end
```

Then, the simple way to get the number of cards that a single school or representative has should be simple.

```
@school.cards.count
@representative.cards.count
```

If you'd to get the number of unique cards, i.e. a card could be associated to multiple programs within the same school or representative and you'd like to count each one only once, then use `distinct`.

```
@school.cards.distinct.count
@representative.cards.distinct.count
```

Now, if you're looking to get the number of cards that *each* school and representative has, that's a bit trickier, but still possible.

```
@schools = School.select('schools.*, count(cards.id)')
                 .joins(programs: { leads: :card } )
                 .group(:id)

@reps = Representative.select('representative.*, count(cards.id)')
                      .joins(schools: { programs: { leads: :card } } )
                      .group(:id)
```

If you'd like the unique number of cards for each school or representative, just change `count(cards.id)` to `count(distinct cards.id)` in the appropriate query.

---

A few notes about these solutions:

- If a school or representative has **zero** cards, they will not appear in in the `@schools` and `@representatives` variables. In order to make them appear, you'll need to adjust the query a bit and use `LEFT JOIN`.
- You probably don't even really need the association to `:cards` in the `School` and `Representative` models to get the counts; you could probably just use the `:leads` association. However, this would make getting distinct a bit more difficult, so that's why I went with `:cards`.

Comment: Thank you @Joe for your very accurate answer.

Comment: No problem! I'm happy to help.